# RPC interface count

Tags: c#, com+

I am trying to monitor the amount of Remote procedure call (RPC) interface count to stop my program before the infamous 256 interface limit.

Right now i am trying to use the following code to get all assembly but i cannot figure out which property gives the actual count or that actually tell me that the interface is taking one of the crucial 256 limits.

```
foreach (var assemblyName in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies())
{
    // get the assembly
    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(assemblyName.ToString());

    // get all types in the assembly
    var types = assembly.DefinedTypes.ToList();
}
```

the types seems good (not sure) but i think i see all classes and interface but there is no property telling me one of them is taking a spot in the interface limit.

Can i have the information i am looking for somehow from the list of assemblies or is there another way to get it ?

[Here is the RPC call limit document from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/890425/you-receive-a-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-complete-this-operati)

I am aware that this error might happen because there is not enough ram available but as far as i know there is around 10-11 gb free on the computers when the issues occur and they all have access to 32 gb of page file.

**After more tests**

I have finally manage to use the `ComVisible` property to figure out which DLL are applicable and it worked. Now that i know which DLL can be problematic i am still stuck at where can i look to find how many RPC interface are currently loaded into my program.

Taking some step back made me think that this kind of information should be somewhere in the current process and not within the DLL reference itself. As the count must be the count of the currently instantiated distinct interface. There is so little information about this kind of problem that it is very very difficult to figure it out.

On the bright side note i figured out how to replicate easily and it's not a specific DLL that throw the error. I made dummy ones with a single class with a string value and when called at the good time it throws the error.

It is probably replicable in a simple test project by creating 260 small unmanaged dll with a different class in each called `Class1` in `dll1.dll` and `Class2` in `dll2.dll` and so on. Then add reference to each 260 dll and instantiate the class in each of them. It will crash on the instantiation of `Class256` in `dll256.dll`. Change the order however you want and it will crash anytime on the 256th instantiation.

I use multiple manufacturer DLL that has between 10 and 100 classes each that are managed and unmanaged and i can only call a few of them before it completely crash the application. So far .NET dll (even those that are not mine) does not seems to count toward this limit. Do not take this as "it actually does not count", I am not sure. It just seems to not affect the count in my primary tests.

### New things came up

We absolutely needed to bypass this limit and still know one has a project of that scale and can figure this out. Out of hope we decided to temporary create separate EXE and pass bunch of commands unsafely in a local text file, make the EXE run and read the text file to know what to do. That EXE has a couple DLL reference that the main project has so it has it's own RPC count limit of 256 that doesn't count toward the main project limit.

Then the EXE run what it need and save the result in the another text file that we wait for it to be created and read it. This is ugly and required months of coding but it work~ish. Main problem is that anti-virus and windows defender blocks all these EXE especially those that access the web and download files so we had to manually contact each of our clients and manually green list all these new EXE files and boy that is long and difficult.

We are still looking for a solution were we can up the limit on windows registry or count the amount of RPC instantiated so we can force the user to shutdown and restart the application as he used more. Why are we still looking for a solution ? Well it's easy, now it completely killed our agile points for each bug. By charts our usual 2 pts went to 8 or 13 pts.

Comment: sounds like an x-y problem - why are you loading up that many assemblies?!?

Comment: What RPC interface limit are you referring to?

Comment: never heard about such a limit. what is it, and which api/library imposes it?

Comment: added the link to the Microsoft document for the limit of 256.

Comment: @DanielA.White I have many third party libraries with each one of them have many class. If you instantiate 20 class from a COM this freezes 20 slot in that 256 limit until you stop the software and restart.

Comment: I assume you would need to check for the `ComVisible` attribute.

Comment: @Amy yes, that was my first guess to at least filter out the .NET dll from my list. Overall i have 253 dll so i didn't feel like hard coding the list and we add more and more everyday. this is why i tough about using reflection to figure this out